# Metrics Sending Interruption Issue with OpenTelemetry in .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, .net-6.0, open-telemetry

I am developing a web application in .NET 6.0 and am using OpenTelemetry for monitoring metrics. However, I am facing an issue: at a certain point, the application stops sending metrics, and the only way to restore functionality is to restart the pool.

- **Technical Details:**

  - Framework: .NET 6.0
  - Language: C#
- **OpenTelemetry Libraries:**

  - OpenTelemetry 1.6.0
  - OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol 1.6.0

**OpenTelemetry Configuration:**
I configured OpenTelemetry in the Program.cs file as follows:

`builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry(builder.Configuration);`

And I have a separate configuration class, MetricsConfigurator.
Here’s a snippet of the OpenTelemetry configuration code:

```
private static readonly AsyncLocal<MetricStreamConfiguration> CurrentCallConfiguration = new();

public static MeterProvider Configure(IConfiguration configuration, Assembly mainAssembly)
{
var appName = mainAssembly.GetName();
var resource = ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
.AddService(serviceName: appName.Name, serviceVersion: appName.Version!.ToString())
.AddAttributes(new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
{
new("server.name", Environment.MachineName),
new("process.id", Environment.ProcessId)
});

var exportInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(configuration.GetValue("OpenTelemetry:ExportIntervalMilliseconds", 60000));

return Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .AddMeter("*")
    .SetResourceBuilder(resource)
    .AddView(instrument =>
    {
        var config = CurrentCallConfiguration.Value;
        CurrentCallConfiguration.Value = null;
        return config;
    })
    .AddOtlpExporter((eo, mo) =>
    {
        eo.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:5110");
        eo.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
        mo.PeriodicExportingMetricReaderOptions = new PeriodicExportingMetricReaderOptions
        {
            ExportIntervalMilliseconds = (int)exportInterval.TotalMilliseconds
        };
        mo.TemporalityPreference = MetricReaderTemporalityPreference.Delta;
    }).Build();
}

public static void AddOpenTelemetry(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
var meterProvider = Configure(configuration, Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
services.AddSingleton(meterProvider);
}

public static Meter UsingConfiguration(this Meter meter, MetricStreamConfiguration configuration)
{
CurrentCallConfiguration.Value = configuration;
return meter;
}
```

**Troubleshooting Attempts:**

- I have checked the application logs, but there are no relevant errors or warnings.
- I have monitored resource usage, and there don’t seem to be issues on this front.
- I have updated all the libraries to the latest available version.
- I have reviewed the OpenTelemetry configuration and there seem to be no errors or conflicts.
- I performed a memory dump of the process of my application when the metrics were not being sent, and I noticed that there were no instances of OpenTelemetry present. After performing a refresh of the connection pool, the instances of OpenTelemetry reappeared, and the metrics began to be sent again.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and knows how to resolve it?
2. Are there suggestions on how I could further diagnose and solve this problem?
3. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

#### **Update 10/04/2023**

**Problem:**
After deploying, telemetry logging in both our projects only works for a limited period. Both applications utilize .NET 6 and initiate OpenTelemetry with slightly different codes. *It's hypothesized that the Garbage Collector prematurely deallocates the MeterProvider instance, perceiving it as non-essential and disrupting ongoing telemetry logging.*

**Attempted Solution:**
I've introduced a static field, Provider, to persist the MeterProvider instance and utilized GC.KeepAlive to prevent the GC from collecting it prematurely.

```
private static MeterProvider Provider;


// Configuration logic...
Provider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    // Configuration logic...
   .Build();

// More configuration logic...
GC.KeepAlive(Provider);
```

Replaced previous logic:

```
services.AddSingleton(meterProvider);
```

**Seeking Guidance:**
While this solution seems to work preliminarily, I'm looking to understand if there are better or optimized ways to ensure the MeterProvider instance isn’t prematurely collected by the GC, or if there are alternative strategies to safeguard telemetry logging without risking potential memory bloat in long-running applications.

Any insights or alternative solutions would be appreciated!

#### **Update 10/11/2023**

Hello all,

Thank you for your ongoing support and discussions on the initial query.

I'd like to bring attention to our continued investigation into the gRPC communication issues that have persisted, even after adjusting our configuration class and deploying the solution to an AWS STG environment. Our implementation ran smoothly for approximately 3 hours before errors started emerging.

**Error Encountered:**

```
2023-10-10T07:38:24.9429543Z: Exporter failed to send data to collector to {0} endpoint... Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: The response ended prematurely while waiting for the next frame from the server.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.")
```

This error seems to occur despite the collector and application residing on the same machine, suggesting network issues are not the likely culprit.

**Progress & New Challenges:**
Upon identifying that the test environment hadn’t been logging for over an hour, revealing a specific error in the trace, we took the following actions:

1. Restarted the connection pool on two web servers in a sticky session sequentially, with metrics sent successfully after an operation post each restart.
2. Analyzed active communication processes with the collector, noticing no attributable processes from our application before the pool restarts and the appearance of processes post-restart.
   Metrics are accurately captured, but ***communication difficulties with the gRPC service arise, notably only when the application operates on framework 6.0, in-process on IIS, and is hosted on AWS.***

**Request for Insights:**
We are exploring potential leads that might indicate whether this error stems from the collector side and focusing on investigating the IOException, where the response ends prematurely while waiting for the next frame from the server.

This integration of insights and errors from our recent endeavours is aimed at providing a comprehensive view of our journey and the stumbling blocks we’re encountering.

Your expertise and suggestions are invaluable, and we appreciate any input that might assist in navigating through these challenges. Let's continue this insightful discussion and work towards a resolution together.

Thank you for your patience, understanding, and collaborative spirit!

#### OpenTelemetry Logging Error: Task Cancellation Exception with Grpc.Core

**Description:**

I've been consistently encountering an error when trying to write logs with OpenTelemetry.
The error suggests that there's a task cancellation happening when reaching out via the gRPC channel. Here's the error message:

```
Failed to write logs to OpenTelemetry due to System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Reached deadline.
   at Grpc.Core.Channel.<WaitForStateChangedAsync>d__16.MoveNext() in /path/obfuscated/Grpc.Core/Channel.cs:line 146
... [rest of the stack trace is similar to provided, but with paths obfuscated]
   at Obfuscated.OpenTelemetryLogProvider.<Flush>d__39.MoveNext() in /path/obfuscated/OpenTelemetryLogProvider.cs:line 250
```

This error happens at an unspecified frequency and seems to be related to the gRPC channel state change mechanism. This might be causing a delay or inability to log data, which is crucial for our operations.

Any assistance or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple of things to try... Add logging of the underlying eventsource https://martinjt.me/2023/07/14/i-finally-found-a-use-for-logging-in-net/ and add the console exporter for the metrics too. They might be able to show you something you're missing.

Comment: The other thing to think about would be when the Singleton is disposed, do you have something running that will resolve it and keep hold of it? The underlying extension use a backgroundservice for that purpose.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for addressing my issue. I have not implemented any custom code for the singleton's finalization (deletion). I am confident that the issue is correlated with .NET 6, as within our suite of applications, only the two that have been migrated to .NET 6 are experiencing this problem. I eagerly await your insights. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd work on the other suggestions then.

Comment: @Martin : Added logs but no result found ...

Comment: So nothing appears in the logs after its shutdown? No shutting down message etc? What about starting up messages? Are you seeing those?

Comment: I'd definitely be looking at having something running in the background that holds onto the tracer/metricproviders rather than relying on them living in the serviceprovider. I don't know how the GC works with things that are in the serviceprovider.

Comment: @Martin Martin, I am now refining the logs to understand what is happening. Additionally, I've tried using a static variable instead of a singleton to reference the MeterProvider, but I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Using dotMemory, I observed memory, taking a dump when metrics were collected and another when they stopped. A notable difference is the absence of MeterProvider.

I tried storing the MeterProvider in a private static field, which seems to resolve the issue. Before finalizing this change, I need to understand the reason behind this solution, but I haven't found any relevant literature. Insights or advice would be appreciated! #coding #development #programming

Comment: If the MeterProvider gets disposed, you'll lose the logs. My guess would be that the GC in .NET is disposing of it, event though it's a singleton, because nothing is using it.

Comment: @Martin I'm diving deeper into investigating this because, in some of my production environments, the problem persists even after applying the updates described. I've enabled the logging with the command: `setx OTEL_LOG_LEVEL "debug" /M`, but no logs are being recorded in the path: `%ProgramData%\OpenTelemetry .NET AutoInstrumentation\logs`. Any ideas on what might be going wrong or additional steps I might take to troubleshoot this? Thank you for your insights!

Comment: @Martin Considering these aspects and the additional information that the problem is being observed only on applications hosted on AWS using Framework 6.0 - as opposed to those on Azure using Framework 4.8 which are running smoothly - it's evident that our issue is intricately tied to the IIS context in which the application is running, and potentially the interaction with the specific environment and framework version.

Comment: @Martin I put an integration in the question. Could you help me?